# Creating multiple directories for users

Tags: directory, subdirectory

I am using gatekeeper for access to pages on server.
This is done by creating directories with an index file in them. This then directs whoever inputted the password to a specific page.
I would like to be able to produce lots of directories with either not long random names or assigned names from say a database as creating many by a manual process is not practical.
Can someone tell me how to generate lots of directories on the fly?
Would be even better if users could create their own directory but thats probably something else. 
Thanks

Comment: Creating directories on a server can be accomplished with a simple bash command, this can easily be extended to create multiple directories at once. Do you have access to bash?  https://www.garron.me/en/bits/mkdir-create-multiple-directories-in-one-command.html

Comment: Hi I have admin rights on my server but Unfortunately I am not familiar with Bash.

Comment: Ok so I found someone who can help me with bash. What command is needed?

Comment: Try the code in the link I posted

Comment: Sorry ratskin I missed that. Ok will look. And if I wanted to have an index page in each directory?

Comment: `mkdir -p foo/bar{00..50} && touch foo/bar{00..50}/index.txt`. Replace `foo/bar` with your directory name and location, `50` with the number of dirs to make, and replace `index.txt` with your index file name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have bash (shell) access on your server, you can execute a simple bash script to create directories with a file in each.

```
for f in foo/bar{00..50}; do mkdir -p $f && touch $f/index.txt; done
```

Replace:

- `foo/bar` with your directory
- `50` with the number of directories
- `index.txt` with the name of the file

If you want to additionally write text to each file, then do this instead

```
for f in foo/bar{00..50}; do mkdir -p $f && printf "text\n goes\n here" > $f/index.txt; done
```

Comment: Sounds good. I am not sure but it might be safer also if I wanted to say make 50 directories on my pc and just upload them after can that be done? Thanks

Comment: I'm sure it can, but without specifying your operating system or the way you'd prefer to upload them, it will be hard for me to help you with it.

Comment: Sorry I did think about that after ;) ..So I am generally using Linux (ubuntu) but also have mac.  Uploading directly from pc by cPanel file manager. Thanks

Comment: Then, the easiest way would be to run the above code in terminal (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingTheTerminal), then open the file manger and zip the folders into one archive, then upload the zip file, then unzip it on the server `unzip archive.zip`. It is of cause possible to upload the directories without compressing (and uncompressing) them, but that will require more bash

Comment: Sounds cool...Thanks.. Gonna go off and have a try, back later Thank Tony

Comment: Hi @Antony if this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: Hi Ratskin Sorry for late reply I didnt spot the note before. The answer was right in part, I am still looking to refine this. Your suggestions were correct but I also need to see how to create some different content in the index files.